Really old horror movie about babies, can’t find out online
It’s an old movie, my girlfriend’s mom watched once and from what she remembers: It’s probably from Victorian era with women wearing those puffy gowns and stuff. A woman is pregnant, and she moves in a mansion.
There’s a fountain inside and her room had painting of babies on the ceiling.
She keeps hearing cries in the night. Turns out, among the previous owner couple, the husband used to kill every unborn child in his wife’s womb, and the woman died there, and her ghost is trying to warn the current woman of all the horrible things done to her.
Another thing: baby heads/bodies are carved on the ornate bed, and they sometimes spook out the current lady living there.
Any help would be appreciated!

That might be The Haunting (1999).
Know that this is a remake of the 1963 film, "The Haunting."

Three people get paid to spend the night in a haunted mansion. They think 
  that they are there for a insomnia experiment but are really there for
  an experiment in fear. Once there they all are haunted by the ghosts
  of the children and the man and woman who were killed in the mansion.

Children carvings around the house:

Children carvings on the bed's headboard:


+1 as this was my first thought as well

Those heads would creep me out without the haunting itself.
